# Character greater than/less than // javascript

Tags: javascript

Ok so I know you can do greater than or less for numbers, but is there a way I can do it for a piece of text.

For example, an input field will check if the text entered is between 1 and 100 characters. If it is not between this length it will say "error" and if it is between this length it will say "good".

Comment: [String.localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

Comment: Compare the length of the strings

Comment: `myString.length > otherString.length`???

Comment: You can set `maxlength="100"` for an input to restrict input till 100 characters as well

Answer (score 2):

for this you can get the string length and check if its less than 100

```js
var str = "Hello World!";
var n = str.length;
console.log(n, n < 100)
```

So the output will be 12 and you can easily check if its below 100